# how to unserialize posted data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

so I think I am a bit lost as to what I am even trying now I'm so tired.

basically I have 4 checkboxes their values are a number.

so lets say my HTML source is like this:

```
<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[1]" value="1"/>
<input class="extra" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checks[2]" value="2"/>
<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[3]" value="3"/>
<input class="extra" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checks[4]" value="4"/>
```

I want to post checks[] with jquery post as it would be posted with PHP, I am very new to this and confused with people just saying 'serialize', which then leads to me getting lost using serialize.

```
checks[1] is empty
check[2] = 2
checks[4] = 4
```

i want it essentially like that ^ on the other side.

I am serializing it like so:

```
var post_data = $('input[name^="checks"]:checked').serialize();
```

post it like so:

```
 $.post('search_item.php', post_data { 'option[]':option, save: form.save.value, item: form.item.value, name: form.i_name.value, desc: form.i_desc.value, text: form.i_text.value },
        function(output)    {
            $('#return2').html(output).show();
        });
```

now accessing it the other side its structured like so:

checks[0] = c
checks[1] = h
checks[2] = e
 etc.

so can please someone tell me how this actually works? Because I am exhausted and very confused.

many thanks,

joe

Answer (score 0):

```
var post_data = $('input[name^="checks"]:checked').serialize();
```

try `$.post('search_item.php', post_data, ...)`

you should received the input in the format you want

```
checks[1] is empty
check[2] = 2
checks[4] = 4
```

Comment: thankyou for helping me, I believe I am trying to post it wrong, ive updated with .post code.